# How to make an https post using node.js library form-data?

Tags: node.js, https, form-data

We  have a client with an api that requires posts over https. We have a node.js application and have been using felixge's node-form-data package (https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data) in order to make the submissions. While the calls work fine against the client's test http-based api, when we attempt to call the production api which uses https the api responds with 400's which the client is telling us is due to the calls coming in over http.

Any ideas as to how we can specify https in our submission?

Our code looks like this:

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
    var couponForm = new FormData();
    couponForm.append('data','{"coupon":{"code":"' + couponCode + '", "discount": "' + discountPercentage + '", "type": "percent", "product": "' + productId + '", "times": "1", "expires": "' + couponExpiresDt + '"}}');

couponForm.submit({hostname:config.client_api_host, path:'/api/coupon/add', auth:auth}, function(err, res) {
      res.resume();

      if (err) {
        logger.log('error', 'Client API createDiscount post error:');
        logger.log('error', {err: err});
        callback(err);
      } else if (res.statusCode != 200) {
        logger.log('error', 'Client API createDiscount post response error:');
        console.log('error', res);
        logger.log('error', {statusCode: res.statusCode});
        logger.log('error', {body: res.body});
        callback(new Error('Client API createDiscount post response error:', res.statusCode));
      } else {
        logger.log('info', "Client coupon code " + couponCode +  " has apparently been created");
        callback(null, {coupon_code: couponCode, expires: couponExpiresDt});
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data/blob/master/lib/form_data.js#L309-L313) you need to pass in `protocol: 'https:'` in your options.

```
couponForm.submit({
    hostname: config.client_api_host,
    path: '/api/coupon/add',
    auth: auth,
    protocol: 'https:'
}, function(err, res) {
    [...]
});
```

Comment: Thanks you thank you!  We are crunch time with the client and this was a HUGE help!

Comment: You're welcome. :) Slightly confused as to why it's `https:` and not just `https` though.